# Running an application on a second server with a dynamic IP. Do I need two SSL certificates when using Apache ProxyPass?

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, proxypass

**Terms**

`example.com`: The domain that points to the `static server`.

`static server`: This server has a static IP address and has Apache ProxyPass pointing to `dynamic server`.

`dynamic server`: This server sits behind a dynamic IP address and hosts the `application`.

`application`: A web application running on the `dynamic server`.

**Intro**

I have an `application` that will be running from `dynamic server` and the domain `example.com` is pointed to another server I control that has a static IP `static server`.

The user will go to the domain `example.com` and this domain will hit `static server.

I have Apache ProxyPass configured to send these requests to my `dynamic server`.

**Side note**

There will be a script on `dynamic server` that updates the Apache virtual host on `static server` whenever the IP changes. (And then another script on the `static server` will restart Apache when the virtual hosts file is modified.) These are almost complete and not the issue at the moment.

**Question**

Do I need to install two SSL certificates for both `static server` and `dynamic server`?

Here is a layout of the setup and the way I believe it should work:

`example.com` points to `static server` with a SSL certificate and then ProxyPass's to `dynamic server`with its own SSL certificate.

Is that correct? Or do I only need one SSL certificate? If I only need the one, which server should it go onto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on what you are trying to achieve with TLS certificates.

If you need authentication and encryption for the client then you will need to have a TLS certificate for `static server`.

If the connection between `static server` and `dynamic server` is secure (such as over a private network or VPN) then you may not need HTTPS between the two, in which case a HTTP connection will suffice.

However, if it's over (for example) the Internet, you'll need a second TLS cert on `dynamic server` to authenticate and encrypt the traffic between the two.  If `static server` is the only user of `dynamic server` then you could use a self-signed certificate for this, or operate your own CA.

A TLS certificate on `static server` does not mean that the traffic between that and `dynamic server` is over HTTPS - you still need a certificate on `dynamic server` for that connection to be secure. Equally, a cert on `dynamic server` doesn't mean that the traffic between clients and `static server` is over HTTPS.  They are two independent connections essentially.